# Generate all numbers for 0 to 1 using a loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

This question might seem a bit silly..:) But I think I'm missing something somewhere..so bit confused...

I wanted to generate all numbers from 0 to 1. In other words, if I do `1/2`, I get `0.5`. Then `0.5/2 = 0.25`. Then `0.25/2 = 0.125`. This will go on until `0.00000001` (A total of 26 divisions)

But I want to generate all numbers in an increasing order from `0.00000001` to `1`.

I tried doing something like so...

```
            let first = 0.00000001
            let last = 1.0
            let interval = first * 2

            let sequence = stride(from: first, to: last, by: interval)

            for element in sequence {
                print(element)
            }
```

But it's not working. It seemed it just prints infinitely...

How can I properly use a for loop and print from `0.00000001` to `1` in a limited number of iterations..? Or any other loops to be used in this case..?

Comment: Just to confirm: you want to multiply the value you print by 2 each time?

Comment: Since I went on dividing and reached till 0.00000001 in 26 iterations, I felt multiplying up from 0.00000001 will do fine. So tried multiplying...My understanding could be wrong also..@Sweeper

Comment: Can you show the dividing code?

Comment: I didn't divide through code. Just used calculator for dividing...(Starting from 1/2, I divided all the resulting numbers till I reached 0.00000001.A total of 26 times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `stride`. `stride` produces an arithmetic sequence with a difference of `interval`, which is `0.00000002`:

```
0.00000001
0.00000003
0.00000005
0.00000007
...
```

You want a geometric sequence between 0 and 1.

You could use [`sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2015879-sequence) instead, which generates an infinite sequence:

```
let first = 0.00000001
let last = 1.0

for item in sequence(first: first, next: { $0 * 2 }).prefix(while: { $0 < last }) {
    print(item)
}
```

`{ $0 * 2 }` is the function that generates the next element, and `prefix(while:)` is used to get first elements that satisfy the `< last` condition.

Comment: I tried printing @Sweeper..and this is the sequence I got...`1e-08
,2e-08,
 4e-08,
 8e-08,
1.6e-07,
 3.2e-07,
 6.4e-07,1.28e-06
, 2.56e-06,
,5.12e-06,1.024e-05,2.048e-05,4.096e-05,8.192e-05,0.00016384, 0.00032768
, 0.00065536
, 0.00131072,0.00262144,0.00524288,0.01048576,0.02097152,0.04194304, 0.08388608,0.16777216,0.33554432,0.67108864`

Comment: The number 1 is also no printed..and this seems to be a sequence different from the one I got while dividing each number by 2...

Comment: Nothing...I was just concerned why the sequence I got by normal division is different from this...also I would like to have the number `1` also to be printed in the `item`...

Comment: @D.M yes, of course it is. You can’t get 1 by keep multiplying 0.00000001 by 2. Just think about it. Can you get a multiple of 10 by multiplying 1 by 2? The 0.00000001 on your calculator is not exactly 0.00000001.

Comment: ok @Sweeper. So you're saying the approach that is followed here is the correct one itself. Only the differences are in the decimal variations which is fine and expected..?

Comment: @D.M Yes, the actual value that will multiply to 1 is 1.490116119384765625 × 10^-8, which I' not sure if it can be accurately represented with 64-bit floating point.

Comment: Ok @Sweeper...agreed. Suppose my first number is `0.0625`, then I'll reach 1 in about 4 iterations. But the above code has this `....prefix(while: { $0 < last })` because of which the number 1 will be omitted. In that case how can I include the number 1 also..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218679/discussion-between-sweeper-and-d-m).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way you could approach it.  Use `stride` to count down the powers of `2` from `26` to `0` and divide `1.0` by that power of `2` and display only the first 8 decimal places:

```
for n in stride(from: 26, through: 0, by: -1) {
    print(String(format: "%.8f", 1.0 / pow(2.0, Double(n))))
}
```

or equivalently (removing the 1/n by using negative exponents):

```
for n in -26...0 {
    print(String(format: "%.8f", pow(2.0, Double(n))))
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.00000001
0.00000003
0.00000006
0.00000012
0.00000024
0.00000048
0.00000095
0.00000191
0.00000381
0.00000763
0.00001526
0.00003052
0.00006104
0.00012207
0.00024414
0.00048828
0.00097656
0.00195312
0.00390625
0.00781250
0.01562500
0.03125000
0.06250000
0.12500000
0.25000000
0.50000000
1.00000000
```